# Does windows block async web service calls?

Tags: web-services, asynchronous

I have a windows application ( C# app ) and it gets all data from an asp.net web service. It works great on my development PC but not some other computers. When i run the application on an another  computer, it opens connections to the web service simultaneously, but some of request not completing.

I watch the web service requests from Fiddler and TCPView.. I think windows blocking simultaneously connections to the same web service address, but I can not catch the real problem is where?

here is the my web service reference override;

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest wr = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest wrHttp = wr as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
    if (wrHttp != null)
    {
        wrHttp.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        wrHttp.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 200;
        wrHttp.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 200;
        wrHttp.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 200, 200);
        wrHttp.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        wrHttp.KeepAlive = false;
        wrHttp.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
    }
    return wr;
}
```

Comment: firewall? The scenario that you describe is quite normal and should work. Check the firewall, which answer do the client get?

Comment: Thanks @Rafa but there is not a firewall.